# What are Ubuntu 10.04 LTS system requirements?

Tags: system-installation

I have tried to install Ubuntu 10.04 LTS beside Windows 7 on my laptop. 
Specs:

- 2GB RAM
- 32bit 2.10GHz
- 300GB Hard Disk
- core2

It used to make my laptop very hot. Any suggestions please?

Comment: This issue is most likely related to your graphics card. Find out which one you have and try searching for related issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the answers [here](http://forum.raymond.cc/linux/20194-minimum-recommended-system-requirements-for-ubuntu-10-04-a.html) might supply you with the answer you seek.

Answer (score 0):

You could try newer ubuntu version. Older linux kernels have terrible power-savings issues. I had similar problems with my laptops (processor just works all the time although it should be idle as there is no activity).